# Правильное отображение потокового видео WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, opencv

Доброго времени суток всем. Появилась необходимость работать с изображениями, которые берутся с камеры. Изображение с камеры выводится в реальном времени на форму. Делаю через OpenCVSharp. Взял компонент VideoCapture.
Ничего лучше не нашел как отображать кадры на Image.

$ Image DataContext="{Binding ManagerProvider}" Source="{Binding Image}"

Обновление происходит в бесконечном цикле

```
public BitmapSource Image { get; set; }
var _video = new VideoCapture(CaptureDevice.Any)
Task.Factory.StartNew(startVideo);

private void startVideo() {
        while (_isWork) {
            if (_video.Read(_mat)) {
                try {
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { Image = _mat.ToWriteableBitmap(); }));
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.Error();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Но все эта конструкция дико нагружает проц, к тому же иногда моргает картинка. Подскажите, может есть другой способ вывести видео в реальном времени?
Пока работает вебка, возможно скоро появится ip-камера

Comment: Тоже интересен этот вопрос.